# Cassandra performance of first Clustering Key

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, composite-primary-key, database-partitioning

I am using Cassandra 3.x and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sp_db.prod_tag 
(
    year int,
    name text,
    group int,
    sn text,
    factory_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year), name, group)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name ASC, group ASC);
```

I have inserted 1 million rows and I started to perform queries:

Query #1 - on partition key

```
select count(*) 
from sp_db.prod_tag  
where year = 2015;
```

Output:

```
    count |
    ------|
    33328 |
```

Query time: **~90ms**

Query #2 - one of clustering keys

```
select count(*) 
from sp_db.prod_tag 
where group = 104 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Result:

```
    count |
    ------|
    3938  |
```

Query time: **~800ms**

We don't pass primary key, therefore Cassandra gets all the rows from the table and it have performance impact.

So far so good...

Querying first from clustering key:

```
select count(*) 
from sp_db.prod_tag 
where name = '06d7d' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Results:

```
    count |
    ------|
    3     |
```

Query time: **~6ms**

And here is my surprise: why only 6ms? There is no primary key, so this query should have poor performance.

Studying documentation I did not find the answer.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concrete reason why the query on `name` should be faster than the query on `group`, assuming you have no secondary index on `name`.

I suspect, but can not prove, that it's a primarily the result of caching at various layers (including the OS page cache).

Edit: re-read the schema

The data will be sorted on disk sorted first by name, then group, so within each partition, it’ll be able to skip to the relevant block of data by name - yes, this is expected and normal.

Comment: Can confirm there is no secondary index. Just pure data model as in question.
This behaviour is reproducible on two, independent environments.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: This is normal and expected of the first clustering - see edit above